# Is there any reason you shouldn't make a class that contains a reference to another class as a field (and is it worth doing anyway)?

Tags: java, class, memory, reference

I'm working on a simple game in java, where the units are classes with their names, health, etc stored in fields.  The units are read in from a file and then stored in a hashmap to form a master library that is used as a reference when new units are spawned.

I'm trying to decide how to store actual units in the game (not the base unit used as a reference but the actual units moving around the map).  Actual units contain more data than the references, such as current health, boosters, etc, but they still need to have access to the original stats, such as maximum health and the like.  To me it seems redundant to have each instance of a unit carry around a bunch of unchanging information that's already stored in the reference, so what I'm thinking of doing is creating a another class to represent spawned units that contains data like current health, etc, as well as a reference to the reference class so that it can still access the basic data.  The code would look something like this (this is just a test code I'm using to test the concept; new to java):

`// start of code

```
public class UnitTest
{
// Main test function.
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("\nStarting test.\n\n");

    ObjectDefinitions.UnitArchetype Base = new     ObjectDefinitions.UnitArchetype("Soldier", 0.8f);
    ObjectDefinitions.Unit Product = new ObjectDefinitions.Unit(Base, 9.0f);

    Base.UnitArchetypeStats();
    Product.UnitStats();

    Base.SetUnitMaxHealth(11.0f);

    Base.UnitArchetypeStats();
    Product.UnitStats();

}
}


class ObjectDefinitions
{
static class UnitArchetype
{
    // Fields
    private String UnitType;
    private float UnitMaxHealth;


    // Constructor
    UnitArchetype(String UnitType, float UnitMaxHealth)
    {

        this.UnitType = UnitType;
        this.UnitMaxHealth = UnitMaxHealth;

    }

    // Methods
    public void UnitArchetypeStats()
    {
        System.out.println("UnitType: " + UnitType + "\nUnitMaxHealth: " + UnitMaxHealth + "\n");

    }

    public void SetUnitMaxHealth(float Health)
    {
        UnitMaxHealth = Health;
    }
}



static class Unit
{
    // Fields
        private ObjectDefinitions.UnitArchetype BaseUnit; // the reference to the base unit
        private float UnitCurrentHealth;

    // Constructor
    Unit(ObjectDefinitions.UnitArchetype Model, float CurrentHealth)
    {
        this.BaseUnit = Model;
        this.UnitCurrentHealth = UnitCurrentHealth;
    }

    // Methods
    public void UnitStats()
    {
        System.out.println("UnitType: " + BaseUnit.UnitType + "\nUnitMaxHealth: " + BaseUnit.UnitMaxHealth + "\nUnitCurrentHealth: " + UnitCurrentHealth + "\n");

    }
}




}
```

So I have two questions.  Firstly, would linking to the base unitin this manner work without causing any problems, or is it liable to break something in the code?

Secondly, is it even worth bothering with something like this, or should I just extend the reference class by adding the extra fields I need and then clone all the information everytime a new unit is spawned, so that each in-game unit contains all the information?  I was trying to optimize for memory, but honestly, even with extra fields for current health and other bits of info, a spawned unit would still only consist of a dozen or so fields.  Is it worth trying to bother with something so tweaked?  I'm coming from a python background and literally learning java as I write this, so I really don't know much about what qualifies as "heavy" in java.

Comment: Take care of java namaing conventions. Method names and variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: not sure what you mean, but if I were you, I would not use static internal classes, but seperate classes

Comment: I didnt read your entire body, but based on your title, there are cases when to include and object of another class as a class field and extending other class instead of using its obj. Its Has-A vs Is-A types of inheritance.

Comment: @Jens Does it make any difference if it's not code I'm collaborating on, or is it just convention?  Does it affect compilation or anything?

Comment: @Stultuske So just define each class at the level of the script, rather than as a part of a nested class?

Comment: @CMB about the naming: it makes your code easier to read. in the long run, you won't be able to figure out anymore what exactly are classes, what are variables/methods, what is an instance call vs a static call . As for the classes, just put them all in their own script. putting too much code in a single file makes for hard to maintain code

Comment: @CMB ist is only a coding convention, that makes you code readable for other peoples

Answer (score 0):

Here are few suggestions:

1. follow java naming conventions.
2. In your Unit Class constructor you have assigned a variable to itself (`this.UnitCurrentHealth = UnitCurrentHealth;`) change it to `this.UnitCurrentHealth = CurrentHealth;`
3. You are using static inner class unnecessarily as your outer class has no other private fields or methods required by your inner classes. If you are doing this because you want to group them then use packages to group them and Move every Class in its own file.
4. you said, you are new to java to for now focus on java features. Once you are confident enough then get your head into 'Design Patterns'.

Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks.  Only started using java since python is too slow for what I'm trying to do, and it's quite the learning curve.